# Make e using 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers

Can you make $e$ with the digits 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9?

You can only use the digits once.

The allowed operators are listed beloẉ.

- Addition
- Subtraction
- Multiplication
- Division
- Square root
- Exponents
- Log, Cos, Sin

You shall not use a operation not listed on the list.

You can only use up to **20** operators.

That is all - Have fun!

Comment: I presume arranging the symbols to form the shape of the letter is not acceptable, despite the phrasing of the question.

Comment: Spoiler: Assuming “Log” is natural log, you can just do $2^{3/Log(8)}$. Of course, this does not work in base 10 log.

Comment: Are we allowed to concatenate digits into larger numbers (e.g. '1' + '2' = '12')?

Comment: @shalop Use `ln` instead of `Log`.

Comment: @DavidHammen `Log` was specifically used in the list of permitted operations. I think shalop has made the right notational choice here.

Comment: *[e](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant))* = Euler's number = Napier's constant = base of the natural logarithms = approx. 2.71828

Comment: @Galen yes, it is allowed.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

> Since we are allowed to use $\sin$ and $\cos$, we can exploit the identity $e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$ to hit $e$ on the nose:
>  $$e=e^{i(-i)}=\cos i-i\sin i=\cos\sqrt{1+2-3+4-5}-\sqrt{6-7}\sin\sqrt{8-9}$$

Comment: Ah, super clever! You can avoid the unary minus (negation is not listed as an allowed operation) while keeping the stylish numerical order of the digits by using, for example,  $1+2-3+4-5$ combined with $6-7$ and $8-9$.

Comment: @Bass Right, I thought subtraction included negation...

Comment: Yeah, that's clearly OP's view too, and since they both basically do the same thing and use the same symbol, the difference is indeed pure semantics. On this site of course, my favourite antics are of the "ped-" variety :-)

Comment: (+1) Mathematically speaking, I think $e^{ix} = \cos x + i\sin x$ only holds for real values of $x$. Otherwise one could do stuff like this: $$1 = 1^i = (e^{2\pi i})^i = e^{-2\pi}.$$

Comment: @Yanko $(a^b)^c\neq a^{bc}$ in general. $$1^i = e^{\log(1^i)} = e^{i \log(1)} = e^{i (\ln|1| + i \arg(1))} = e^{-\arg(1)} = e^0 = 1$$

Answer (score 33):

> I'm not beating Parcly, but here is a classic champion that I looked up at [WolframMathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/eApproximations.html), using only algebraic operations (and thus not hitting exactly):$$\left(1 + 9^{-4^{6\cdot 7}}\right)^{3^{2^{85}}}$$It uses $e\approx (1 + 1/n)^n$, and tries to make $n$ as large as possible. It is apparently correct to $18\,457\,734\,525\,360\,901\,453\,873\,570$ digits.

Comment: Really as stated, amazing. Using WolframAlpha 3^2^85 and 9^4^42 both has the same number of digits and finishes with ......3648803841. Just do not see how to prove those are the same values.

Comment: @z100 It's not a very difficult argument, using only standard power rules and the fact that $9$ and $4$ are squares:$$9^{4^{42}}=(3^2)^{(2^2)^{42}}=3^{2\cdot 2^{2\cdot 42}}=3^{2^{1+84}}$$Alternately, using your WolframAlpha result, you can note that the two expressions are both clearly powers of 3. And powers of 3 with the same final digit and the same number of digits must be the same number (two powers of 3 with the same number of digits must differ by a factor of 1, 3 or 9, and only one of those alternatives preserves the final digit).

Comment: Really cool! How did you compute the number of correct digits?

Comment: @doetoe It was a very hard calculation. The main crux of the proof was looking at the page I linked to, and copy-pasting that number from there.